# HSM Thales PayShield vulnerabilities

Tags: vulnerability, key, hsm

My management requested to investigate about security of HSM Thales Payshield.
Have you ever heard of any security bugs on the HSM Thales Payshield? I mean, except for the known bugs reported in their documentation, it seems impossible to find other information. I am aware that due to their peculiarity of use and software used we are not dealing with common operating systems. But is it possible that no one has ever found vulnerabilities?

Comment: Have you looked up the CVEs? And which product? The 10k is only 4 years old.